# Select database table from arbitrary row number in RFC call

Tags: abap

I successfully deal with selection from SAP Tables by using RFC function module. Issue I'm facing is to understand best practice of selecting data from arbitrary row.

Example: First RFC call will fetch 1000 records from `KNA1` (I will log in custom transparent table how many records in total where considered so far).

New RFC Call should take next 1000 rows but starting from row 1000 till 2000. Is there some elegant way of dealing with this situation?

Using of Cursor is not possible since there are 2 consecutive calls of same RFC cursor value will be reset.

Otherwise I should always selecting everything and distinguish requested data by looping the total data which will consume a lot of time.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you leave the RFC connection alive and don't close the cursor, it remains opened for next calls...

Comment: Hi Sandra. Unfortunately that RFC Connection will be closed and same one will be called all over. It's more like serialization process to retrieve data from SAP System in small packages. Each RFC will transport about 3000 data records. Now I struggle to find a way to do not take them always from beginning and looping in RFC before I get them back. :(

Comment: Did you make sure you have no possibility to let the RFC connection open? Otherwise, did you check whether ABAP Channels (AMC, APC) or ABAP Daemons (ADF) can be used? (I think they live as long as you wish and data is persisted in their own memory session) Unfortunately I never used them so I can't tell more about them, and I even don't know if it's really relevant. You need minimum ABAP >= 7.40 and >= 7.52 for ADF.

Answer (score 2):

## Use OFFSET

In the SELECT with [OFFSET](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_up_to_offset.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@):

```
SELECT * FROM kna1 
  UP TO 1000 ROWS 
  OFFSET (lv_offset)
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY ...
```

If `lv_offset` contains 2000 for example, it will return the rows 2001-3000 by the ordering.

According to the [online help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_up_to_offset.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@), you have to use ORDER BY in the SELECT.

Comment: Hello Andras !  

Thanks for your answer looks very convinient. But I struggle to understand to correct procession. What I have done is :

  REFRESH ET_RET_TABLE.
  SELECT (GV_SELECT_STATEMENT)
    FROM (IV_TABNAME)
    INTO TABLE ET_RET_TABLE
    UP TO GV_PACKAGE_SIZE ROWS
    ORDER BY (GV_PRIMARY_KEYS) ASCENDING
    OFFSET 10.

At the end it takes first 10 records again. OFFSET should somehow define from which record to start if i'm not wrong, right ?

Many thanks for helping.

Comment: @OrdinaryPerson, if the OFFSET value is hardcoded, it will always return the same lines, in your case lines 11-(10+gv_package_size)

Comment: Hi Andras.. My code implementing OFFSET looks like is not considered at all. Somewhere I read that OFFSET is not supported in Open SQL. Currently I'm on Oracle DB but Open SQL is independent of databases. I don't understand on which environment OFFSET is valid to process?

Thank you !

Comment: @OrdinaryPerson You need to use order by apparently

Comment: Support Andras. Selecting from arbitrary row without ORDER doesn't make sense, as ABAP "doesn't know" how rows are physically stored in database. It will select in a random order and cross-sections of datasets are possible.